# Displaying mixed arrays in computed method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, computed-properties

I've got a computed method that allows me to display some data:

```
  productsSpecification() {
    var names = [];
    var numbers = [];
    this.cart.items.forEach(function(item) {
      names += "Item: " + item.product.name + " -";
      numbers += " Amount: " + item.quantity + ", ";
    });
    var together = names + numbers;
    return together;
  }
```

I would like to display elements in order: element from 'names' array + element from 'numbers' array: `'Item: item1 - Amount: 1'`.

Comment: Are you able to use ES6?

Comment: Yeah, I use webpack, but the problem has been solved already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map it like this:

```
productsSpecification() {
  return this.cart.items.map(function(item) {
    return `Item: ${item.product.name} - Amount: ${item.quantity}`; // or "Item: " + item.product.name + " - Amount: " + item.quantity;
  }).join(', ')
}
```

Comment: Probably should note that template strings are ES6, in case the site needs backwards compatibility.

Comment: You can also shorten it if you want: ``return this.cart.items.map(({ quantity, product: { name } }) => `Item: ${name} - Amount: ${quantity}`).join(', ')``

Comment: I also have another computed method so I can add all my `item.quantity`,
I am trying to display it in the method you suggested: 
`return Item: ${item.product.name} - Amount: ${item.quantity} - Total Amount: ${this.quantityTotal}`  but it doesn't work.

Comment: @kabugh it's not `this`, it's `item`